# FIX/FAST to SQL table

Tags: fix

I have FIX/FAST data in CSV format. Sample: 
1128=9|9=131|35=f|49=CME|34=5369745|52=20160314214500017847063|60=20160314214500001317818|75=20160315.....
I need to transfer information into SQL table with tags as names of the fields and
values as data. Can you advise any free or commercial software which could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you any available ETL (Extraction, transformation and loading) tool this conversion. Though, there are several commercial tools available like tableau or tools from SAP and oracle. But I would recommend Pentaho Spoon which is part of [Pentaho Data Integration](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/) (it is a community framework). You can easily create a [flow](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/.02+Creating+a+Transformation+or+Job) for loading the data into SQL table.